Installed Botaniq Lite but can't see assets?
I just upgraded from the starter kit to the Botaniq Lite version. I've installed it but can't see the assets. The starter version is still showing in Blender along with the Lite version. I think I may have to remove the starter install but I can't see how to do that , it does not show up in my addons only the Lite version does.
Has anyone else had this problem?
Thanks.

That's a third-party addon so you'll have to ask the addon author(s) that one. - We can only help with questions about Blender and its built-in addons here.

Okay. Thank you for the info.

you can try to remove the directory of the starter kit, have a look in C:\Users<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender<x.x>\scripts\addons\ and look for starter or botaniq or something related
